# Show function has a dense graph

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f\colon \mathbb R \to \ \mathbb R$ be a function. Let $A\times B\subset\mathbb R$ where $B$ is perfect set ( perfect set is closed without any isolated point). Assume we want to $f\restriction A$ is dense in $A\times B.$ It is enough to show the following $$Gr(f\restriction A) \cap (J\times P^*)\neq\emptyset$$  Where $J= I\cap A$ and $P^*\subset B.$ where $I$ is element of the basis of $\mathbb R$, $P^*$ is a perfect set, and $Gr$ is the graph of function.  Does that right?

Comment: $f \restriction A \times B$ makes no sense, only $f \cap (A \times B)$ makes sense (both are sets of pairs). And generally only very discontinuous functions will have such a dense graph. What if $f$ is constant e.g. ? This is nonsense and false as stated. Fix it.

Comment: Henno, $f\restriction A\times B$ I meant the graph for $f$ usually I do not distinguish between function and its graph. Any way, I said If we want to show that $f\restriction A\times B$ has dense graph in $A\times B$ Is the above condition enough?  ,  .

Comment: You restrict to $B$ in the codomain?how do you determine $A$ then?

Comment: Henno, I fixed , it is clear now.